# Conky: Grabbed text has multiple lines and does not align

Tags: conky

I'm grabbing the output of `u1sdtool --cur` to be reported in my conky. The output is:

```
u1sdtool --cur
Current uploads: 0
Current downloads: 0
```

This text is grabbed in the TEXT part of my conkyrc config file as:

```
${goto 55}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color}U1 SYNC 
${goto 55}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}${exec u1sdtool --cur }
```

Given that the text returned from `u1sdtool --cur` has two lines, the first line will be offset by 55 but the second will not.

See the bottom of the image. I would like to see the 'Current downloads' line be offset at 55 as well. Any idea how to do this?

[image: conky screenlet]

This conky config file is my customized version of hardball's [orange theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/conky_orange?content=137503)

Edit: What I would like to have, ideally, is the correct alignment and, once I do have uploads, see a list of file names. 
Such as eg.

```
U1 SYNC 
Current uploads: 3
  filename.txt 
  filename.jpg 
  filename.zip
Current downloads: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to split the output of `u1sdtool --cur` with `grep`:

```
u1sdtool --cur | grep 'Current uploads:'
u1sdtool --cur | grep 'Current downloads:'
```

Your `conkyrc` would look like:

```
${goto 55}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color}U1 SYNC 
${goto 55}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}${exec u1sdtool --cur | grep 'Current uploads:' }
${goto 55}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}${exec u1sdtool --cur | grep 'Current downloads:' }
```

I will suggest to use `execi` instead to `exec` because `exec` is resource hungry. for more details:

```
man conky
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I experimented with that. The problem is that once I do have up- or downloads going on, it will only report the one line with 'Current uploads'. I changed the grep statement to "grep -e 'Current uploads:' -e path" but then it mixes the up- and downloads up and I only get to see the initial part of the path. One could also add the -c option to get a count. I restated in my original question what I would like to have. Still, your answer was good, so +1 - but not exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!